# What is the feature of field "left" and "right" in jstree jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jstree

I am using jquery plugin jstree to build a tree.

When I execute this plugin's database file, this db has 2 field "left" and "right", so I don't know these fields are used to do what? If I set value of these fields to 0, the tree will show only root note, child notes will not appear.

Please explain me what use of field "left" and "right" in jsTree :)
Thank You!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called [Nested Set Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) and it's used for easy retriving of the whole tree with one db query